# MySQL Partitioning a Table That Contains a Primary Key

Tags: mysql, partitioning

I have a table that I want to partition:

```
CREATE TABLE `tbl_orders` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
    `system_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `updated_at` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE,
    INDEX `system_id` (`system_id`) USING BTREE
)
COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT=8
;

ALTER table tbl_orders
PARTITION BY HASH(system_id)
PARTITIONS 4;
```

**Example of what im trying to achieve:**
I have a table which I want to partition by `system_id` in order to speed up queries.

When I run the partition I get the following error:

> /* SQL Error (1503): A PRIMARY KEY must include all columns in the table's partitioning function */

1. What would I change to run this partition successfully whilst still achieving my aim which is to split the table on `system_id`?
2. Is partitioning this way achievable with a primary key on the table?

Comment: Please show us the query that you hope to speed up.  You already have an `INDEX`; that is much better than `PARTITION BY HASH`.

Comment: The point of my question is to find out how to solve the issue. Please could anyone help with the question itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PARTITIONing` requires you to add the "partition key" (`system_id`) to every Unique index, including the `PRIMARY KEY`.

You will, I predict, find that `PARTITION BY HASH` is useless for performance.  It may even slow down the query.

Please show a query that you hope to speed up; I will advise in more detail.